# Optimize hibernate criteria query to become more dynamic

Tags: java, hibernate

I'm using a hibernate criteria query with lots of conditionals. The query if for a purchase request form which consist of application states and roles. So to keep things simple, all forms are started in state 1 or Draft. When the form is saved, the current user becomes the creator. The creator can assign other users to the form such as an Authorizer or Contact. These are what I consider dynamic roles. So my first three states of the form goes as followed,

```
State 1 "Draft" role Creator
State 2 "Authorizer" role Authorizer
State 3 "Contact" role Contact
```

Once you leave state 3 and enter state 4, the application now enters the admin role. There could be up to 15 states before the form is finally approved and closed out. Up until the last four states, Creator, Authorizer, and Contact will continue to have access. The last four states, they will not have access.

Unless the admin is a creator, authorizer, or contact, the user will not have access to the first three states, but will continue to have access all the way to the very last state including the remaining four the non admin didn't have access too.

My current query looks like the following, however as an admin I would like to do away with having to manually hard code each applicationState to be added to the query and add all of them, but exclude states where the admin isn't in the dynamic role creator, authorizer, or contact.

This query works, but is very messy.

```
Disjunction programRoles = Restrictions.disjunction();
            programRoles.add(Restrictions.eq(Role.ROLE_CREATOR, user));
            programRoles.add(Restrictions.eq(Role.ROLE_AUTHORIZER, user));
            programRoles.add(Restrictions.eq(Role.ROLE_CONTACT, user));

            if(roleManagerService.isAdmin()) {
                programRoles.add(Restrictions.eq("currentState.prStateCode", ApplicationStateEnum.ARCHIVED.name()));
                programRoles.add(Restrictions.eq("currentState.prStateCode", ApplicationStateEnum.ASSESSOR_REVIEW.name()));
                programRoles.add(Restrictions.eq("currentState.prStateCode", ApplicationStateEnum.ASSIGNOR_REVIEW.name()));
                programRoles.add(Restrictions.eq("currentState.prStateCode", ApplicationStateEnum.AUDITOR_REVIEW.name()));
                programRoles.add(Restrictions.eq("currentState.prStateCode", ApplicationStateEnum.BURIED.name()));
                programRoles.add(Restrictions.eq("currentState.prStateCode", ApplicationStateEnum.DEAD.name()));
                programRoles.add(Restrictions.eq("currentState.prStateCode", ApplicationStateEnum.FINAL.name()));
                programRoles.add(Restrictions.eq("currentState.prStateCode", ApplicationStateEnum.FINAL_MAJOR_APPROVAL.name()));
                programRoles.add(Restrictions.eq("currentState.prStateCode", ApplicationStateEnum.FINAL_MINOR_APPROVAL.name()));
                programRoles.add(Restrictions.eq("currentState.prStateCode", ApplicationStateEnum.IFAS_LOAD.name()));
                programRoles.add(Restrictions.eq("currentState.prStateCode", ApplicationStateEnum.PO_COLLECTION.name()));
                programRoles.add(Restrictions.eq("currentState.prStateCode", ApplicationStateEnum.PO_DISTRIBUTION.name()));
                programRoles.add(Restrictions.eq("currentState.prStateCode", ApplicationStateEnum.PO_EVALUATION.name()));
                programRoles.add(Restrictions.eq("currentState.prStateCode", ApplicationStateEnum.PURGE.name()));
                programRoles.add(Restrictions.eq("currentState.prStateCode", ApplicationStateEnum.SECONDARY_MAJOR_REVIEW.name()));
                programRoles.add(Restrictions.eq("currentState.prStateCode", ApplicationStateEnum.SECONDARY_MINOR_REVIEW.name()));
                programRoles.add(Restrictions.eq("currentState.prStateCode", ApplicationStateEnum.SECONDARY_OVERHEAD_REVIEW.name()));
            }

        Criteria results = this.session.createCriteria(PurchaseRequest.class)
                .createAlias("currentState", "currentState")
                .add(programRoles);

                if(!roleManagerService.isAdmin()) {
                    results.add(Restrictions.ne("currentState.prStateCode", ApplicationStateEnum.DEAD.name()))
                            .add(Restrictions.ne("currentState.prStateCode", ApplicationStateEnum.ARCHIVED.name()))
                            .add(Restrictions.ne("currentState.prStateCode", ApplicationStateEnum.FINAL.name()))
                            .add(Restrictions.ne("currentState.prStateCode", ApplicationStateEnum.BURIED.name()));
                }
```

I'm wondering if someone could point me in a direction to clean this up making it much more dynamic.

Comment: Would asking the roleManagerService for Collection<ApplicationStateEnum> candidateApplicationStates() and Collection<ApplicationStateEnum> excludedApplicationStates() work? Then you just do a Restrictions.in or loop to add ne.

You might get some benefit from trying to put that kind of logic into a class that knows whether they are admin or not and can make a decision. Try to limit the scope of that boolean.

Comment: @roby, I could yes, but all of those states are housed in the database and can be dynamically added / subtracted, so I was hoping not to have to hard code any of it. I was almost thinking there must be a way to return all results for admin except for the ones in the first three states that don't contain the current user. I just can't seem to think straight today.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not really tried, but maybe only adding the restrictions the admin user is not allowed to see.
Something like:

```
Disjunction programRoles = Restrictions.disjunction();
programRoles.add(Restrictions.eq(Role.ROLE_CREATOR, user));
programRoles.add(Restrictions.eq(Role.ROLE_AUTHORIZER, user));
programRoles.add(Restrictions.eq(Role.ROLE_CONTACT, user));

// change starts here
if(roleManagerService.isAdmin()) {
    Conjunction notHiddenStateForAdmin = Restrictions.conjunction();
    notHiddenStateForAdmin.add(Restrictions.ne("currentState.prStateCode", ApplicationStateEnum.FIRST_STATE.name()));
    notHiddenStateForAdmin.add(Restrictions.ne("currentState.prStateCode", ApplicationStateEnum.SECOND_STATE.name()));
    notHiddenStateForAdmin.add(Restrictions.ne("currentState.prStateCode", ApplicationStateEnum.THIRD_STATE.name()));
    programRoles.add(notHiddenStateForAdmin);
}

// rest unchanged
Criteria results = this.session.createCriteria(PurchaseRequest.class)
       .createAlias("currentState", "currentState")
       .add(programRoles);

if(!roleManagerService.isAdmin()) {
     results.add(Restrictions.ne("currentState.prStateCode", ApplicationStateEnum.DEAD.name()))
            .add(Restrictions.ne("currentState.prStateCode", ApplicationStateEnum.ARCHIVED.name()))
            .add(Restrictions.ne("currentState.prStateCode", ApplicationStateEnum.FINAL.name()))
            .add(Restrictions.ne("currentState.prStateCode", ApplicationStateEnum.BURIED.name()));
}
```

Comment: Klein-Robbenha The only issue with your solution, is once we go past the third state and enter into the forth state, it only provides me with results containing me as either the creator, authorizer, or contact. Once in the forth state, I will need to see it with all users, so for example if John doe is the creator, authorizer, and contact, I should not see him if the form is in any of those states, but once it makes it out of those states, I should see the result as an admin. The only time I should see any results from those states is if I'm assigned to one of them.

Comment: Ok, back to the drawign board ... hm, instead of creatign a new answer I edited my original one so it now only filter the "forbidden" initial states from the admin (not sure what thir names are , so they are FIRST_STATE ... etc here). Hope this works better.  (Btw should I have created a new answer instead of editing the editing one? I am not sure what is the proper behaviour, as I am quite new here)

Comment: Thanks, so far it appears to be working. I'm running it through our testers this afternoon. Providing no bugs, I'll vote you the best answer. Thanks for all the help.